# Allowing links only in a specific channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I was wondering if any of you guys is able to help me out here, i'd like to make a channel to be links-only, meaning if you try to type or send a message there it will get deleted by the bot saying something like "ERROR! this channel is for links only" just like when you do a filter for links to be deleted. Thank you to whoever could provide any sort of help and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `message` event you can check if the message was sent in the only-links channel if so check `message.content` against a `RegExp()` to determine whether it should be allowed or not.

```js
if (message.channel === message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'links-only')) {
        const linkRegex = new RegExp(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g)
        if (!linkRegex.test(message.content)) {
            message.delete()
            message.reply('this is a link-only channel').then(msg => msg.delete(5000))
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, if you could please reformat the code to v11.5 because i haven't migrated yet to v12, that would be really grateful of you.

Comment: thank you it worked somewhat , i just used the one you provided but somehow the bot doesn't stop after deleting the first message. it keeps sending the 'this is a link-only channel' constantly, pretty much because it's detecting that the bot is sending text there so it's like a loop

Comment: I fixed it, sorry there were missing brackets, if the answer solved your question then please accept it

Comment: no it still the same issue, like i said it's detecting that the bot is sending texts too, therefore it will keep deleting over and over, the only fix i did was to remove the last part where it says message.reply and just kept it message.delete instead

Comment: Oh, you should have `if (message.author.bot) return;` in your `message` event regardless of anything.

Comment: silly me i posted the code above that in my event, thank you btw it works like a charm now, you deserved the approval!